# British or American

Tags: discussion

Does Puzzling (and in general SE) support **British English** or **American English** as official language?
Personally, I prefer American, like most users do.
So, do you mind a mix of both? Or would you like to see only one?
**Express your opinion!**

**EDIT:** As 2012rcampion pointed out, there are some word-puzzles were the spelling differences are significative. In those rare cases, would you consider a good habit for the authors to clarify which language they're using?

Comment: You prefer American English? :-o I thought you were European!

Comment: Link to the corresponding Meta.SE question, for anyone curious: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23869/what-should-the-standard-spelling-be-british-or-us

Comment: I think 'like most users do' is a bit presumptuous. Have you asked the population of India whether they reach for OED or Merriam-Webster? [helpful link](http://www.amazon.in/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_c_0_10/277-1376663-6815762?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=dictionary&sprefix=dictionary%2Caps%2C384)

Comment: In cases where spelling matters to the puzzle it is even more important that it should not be editing as you might break the puzzle.

Comment: @Bob Indeed; this is why I'm very wary of editing riddles unless they're been solved.

Answer (score 13):

**I support coherent English.**

As long as you make sense, it really doesn't matter too much how you spell things. Dialect differences tend to be reasonably coherent to other speakers, so I'm not sure we need to worry about asking for anything other than clarity.

Comment: In some word-based puzzles, the differences in spelling might make a difference.  This should be pretty rare enough that it can be handled on a case-by-case basis though.

Answer (score 10):

I'm a native speaker of British English, and can't see why I should be forced to speak in a different dialect in order to participate in a Q&A forum. Both are perfectly intelligible to speakers of the other (there may be a few words like pavement/sidewalk which are different, but in general the differences are minor ones of spelling: centre/center, colour/color, travelling/traveling), so **both should be considered acceptable**.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but would another example being grey/gray?

Comment: @warspyking Yep. And plough/plow is another one.

Answer (score 9):

***Both are ok***, and so edits which amend another person's writing from one to the other should be avoided.

[Tomato, tomato.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Let%27s_Call_the_Whole_Thing_Off)

Comment: I wonder if it's significant that this question has got 2 answers from Brits and one from an American... ;-)

Comment: +1 for pointing out that editing to change someone's valid British or American spelling is wrong because both are ok.